# Securely erasing all data on iPod Classic so that it cannot be recovered

Tags: ipod, recovery, data-recovery, ipod-classic

Restoring iPod Classic would not work because it simply erases "offsets" to data. Is there any software dedicated to this? Since iPod Classic has many system files on the root, I'm not able to use any kind of software that blow up the whole drive. FYI, I'm a Windows user.

Comment: Smash it with a hammer into oblivion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're a Windows user I'm not entirely sure how the iPod classic will or won't work in Disk Mode or how your Windows formatting software of choice will *see* your iPod. However, on a Mac you can securely erase an iPod Classic, so it may well be possible with Windows.

However, in the absence of certainty, why not just fill it up with *irrelevant* data first? This will force a *write* over the storage.

For example, you could fill it with a whole bunch of music (or anything else really) and after it's full, then wipe it/restore it/etc. Then do with it as you wish in the knowledge that anyone seriously trying to recover the *original* data (i.e. the data you had on it *before* you filled it with irrelevant data) will have almost no chance of recovering anything meaningful.